# Cannot use extract method function in Visual Studio Code when coding in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I want to use the extract method function on this line of code in Visual Studio Code:

```
GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = hit.point;
```

This is the whole function:

```
    private void MoveToCursor()
    {
       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
       RaycastHit hit;
       bool hasHit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
       if (hasHit)
       {
           GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().destination = hit.point;
       }
    }
```

I've tried using Ctrl+., Ctrl+Shift+R, with no success. There is also no lightbulb coming up, and the setting is on. The extensions I have installed are the official C# extension, and Unity Code Snippets. Help is much appreciated and I'd be happy to provide more information if it's necessary(but I think there is enough).

Comment: If you want to to move the code to a method then just do it?

Comment: I'm doing a course on udemy, and they just clicked a lightbulb and named the method. I'm new to this stuff, so could you explain what you mean by just do it?

Comment: Don't know Visual Studio Code, but try the 'Edit' menu. Does it have a 'Refactor' item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by going into unity and changing the code editor. This was done by selecting the preferences menu, then selecting external tools or searching it, and changing the external script editor to Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by installing this extension into vs code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HarryHopkinson.extract-method

Before, clicking the bell after selecting part of the code in the UI,  wouldn't do anything.